# LVM snapshot: Failed to wipe snapshot exception store, udev doesn't create the partition before lvm tries to wipe it

Tags: lvm, udev, snapshot

I am trying to create a snapshot of a logical volume (partition) but I cannot make it work. After days of researching, I found that [this post](https://linux-lvm.redhat.narkive.com/9Pu8Wro2/lvcreate-device-not-cleared-aborting-failed-to-wipe-start-of-new-lv#selection:3.344.74) might shed some light on the situation. We are using the Yocto project for the basis of our OS.

I am using `lvcreate -L 8M -n conf_snap -s /dev/mapper/l4m-conf -v` and this generates the following:

```
Overriding default 'mirror_region_size' setting with 'raid_region_size' setting of 2048 kiB
Setting chunksize to 4.00 KiB.
Archiving volume group "l4m" metadata (seqno 15).
Creating logical volume conf_snap
Creating volume group backup "/etc/lvm/backup/l4m" (seqno 16).
activation/volume_list configuration setting not defined: Checking only host tags for l4m/conf_snap.
Creating l4m-conf_snap
Loading table for l4m-conf_snap (252:8).
Resuming l4m-conf_snap (252:8).
/dev/l4m/conf_snap: not found: device not cleared
Aborting. Failed to wipe snapshot exception store.
Removing l4m-conf_snap (252:8)
Creating volume group backup "/etc/lvm/backup/l4m" (seqno 17).
```

1. `systemd-udevd.service` is up and running
2. `vigdisplay` outputs

```
 --- Volume group ---
 VG Name               l4m
 System ID
 Format                lvm2
 Metadata Areas        2
 Metadata Sequence No  17
 VG Access             read/write
 VG Status             resizable
 MAX LV                0
 Cur LV                7
 Open LV               6
 Max PV                0
 Cur PV                2
 Act PV                2
 VG Size               952.85 GiB
 PE Size               4.00 MiB
 Total PE              243930
 Alloc PE / Size       236533 / <923.96 GiB
 Free  PE / Size       7397 / 28.89 GiB
 VG UUID               A2tiw5-tF9k-pIjQ-a9W5-4LbN-LcR3-mVMzCi
```

3. `lsblk` outputs

```
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                8:0    0 924.1G  0 disk
|-sda1             8:1    0   100M  0 part
`-sda2             8:2    0   924G  0 part
  `-l4m          252:0    0   924G  0 crypt
    |- (...)
    |-l4m-conf   252:4    0    20M  0 lvm   /mnt/conf
    |- (...)
sdb                8:16   0  14.9G  0 disk
| (...)
sdc                8:32   1  28.9G  0 disk
```

The `sdc` device is a USB storage device that I added to VG using `pvcreate` and `vgextend`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is nice, posting an answer to your own bountied question. When I say nice, of course I mean not.

The reason why LVM fails to create the snapshot volume is because of a glitch in `udev` version 239 and 240 [discussed here](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/11255). There it says that LVM volumes are not properly initialized by the `udev`. When this is put together with information found in [this thread on RedHat narkive](https://linux-lvm.redhat.narkive.com/9Pu8Wro2/lvcreate-device-not-cleared-aborting-failed-to-wipe-start-of-new-lv#selection:3.344.74), it seems pretty clear that this error is due to the `udev` version.

To fix this I would need to update my `udev`, but since it comes bundled in `systemd` of [OpenEmbedded](https://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Main_Page) this is not an option at this time.

I hope this helps someone.